# Where can I ask a question asking for recommendations for note-taking software that supports Markdown formatting?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask a question that looks like this?

> What are some popular general-purpose note-taking software apps that support Markdown formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question would belong on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but please be sure to check their requirements before posting. In particular, they want questions to clearly list all requirements for software, and for questions to specifically ask for one piece of software that fulfills those requirements.